# How should I determine the lowest runable vscode version on my extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The question is quite straightforward, how should I set the minimum required VSCode version on my extension? Should I add the version I'm working on? That doesn't sound optimal. Should I generate a random number? Should I collect all the APIs and manually check their version requirements? Any better idea?

Comment: For an initial release, I'd just go with the current latest VSCode release as the minimum, and afterwards increase as needed if you use new APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code's main API is versioned and backwards compatible. To see which apis are available in a specific VS Code version such as `1.34`, simple install `"@types/vscode": "^1.34.0"` and check your extension code against that (either using TypeScript or by [type checking your JavaScript](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_type-checking)).

If you are unsure about which specific version to use however, your safest bet to require the latest version of VS Code. The adoption rate of new releases is fairly rapid

Comment: My target audience is actually behind an air-gapped network which makes updating a hassle, so I can't know if they've got the latest version or some ancient. So I'd like to be as permissive as I just can :) Installing those types is actually a nice idea. So you say if tslint does not break on that specific version there's a great chance that my code is compatible with it? :) Thanks.

Comment: In general, yes. `@types/vscode` will check the JS/TS api. If your extension uses built-in VS Code commands, you should also check to make sure those commands are supported in older versions